# $.ajax parsing issue (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, parsing, nested

So I have an array:

```
[{'key1':'a', 'key2':'b', 'ProblemKey': {'keyP1': 'c', 'KeyP2':'d'}}, {'key1':'e', 'key2': 'f', 'ProblemKey': ....}}]
```

When I do the standard $.each loop through the received data (above) from my GET response, all of the keys correspond correctly to their value for each object in the array except the "problemKey"s (because their values are associative arrays and not strings?).  Those always come back as Undefined.  Is there any way to get the $.ajax method to parse these parts correctly?  Or should I return the data as a text document and get some third party plugin that has better parsing abilities than the one that comes with jQuery already?

Answer (score 1):

In your `$.ajax` call, set the `dataType` to `"json"`:

```
$.ajax({
   // other stuff
   dataType: "json"
});
```

Then in the `success` function you can access the return value with the dot operator:

```
var myVal = returnArray[0].ProblemKey.keyP1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
            url:'Your post url',
            data : ({
                'elem':elemtopost,

            }),
            method : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',                 
            success: function(msg){ 

                    for(j=0;j<msg.length;j++){
                            alert(msg[j]['key1']  //accessing the json string
                    }
});
```